# How to access all subcategories' products

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables :

The first is category which have columns: id, name, parent_category_id
The second is products which have columns: id, name, price, category_id

Now each category may have other subcategories and each of the subcategories may also have subcategories so how using eloquent I can retrieve all products of the category and all of it is subcategories?

Comment: Your current format would require recursive SQL, which is not an ideal approach. I would suggest looking into storage formats that do not require recursive SQL. I recommend searching for "[Laravel Eloquent Nested Set](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Laravel+Eloquent+Nested+Set)", which would use a tree format internally to store hierarchical data.

Comment: I too, recommend using a nestedset library. It solves your problem in the easiest and prettiest way

Comment: @halfer thanks for the tip. Looking deeper into it I found this package https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset this is probably what you mean. It is L5.8 compatible. Bookmarked for future need.

Answer (score 1):

Your category file is not Relational, but it is correct for your stated use.  Standard SQL is recursive.  There are many freeware pieces of software, which use the term SQL without providing the features and functions of SQL.

- If you are using one of those, you are stuck.  Find out whatever works on that non-SQL software.
- All such methods will be, by definition, anti-Relational, and therefore horrendous.  There is nothing "easy" or "pretty" in that.

If you have genuine SQL:

- code a recursive Function that produces the tree (your file describes a hierarchy of categories) for a single `product.category_id`, in a scalar variable (single column)
- use `DISTINCT` to eliminate duplicates
- use `SELECT ... WHERE category_id IN ( FunctionName() )`